# I have an indenting issue: my function returns 0.0, instead of a calculated value

Tags: python, html, forms, calculator

I wrote a code for a damage calculator in Pokemon, that would return a calculated value (based on a damage formula) if given the required data in the html form. I'm absolutely sure that the html form is correct, but the calculator itself will return 0.0 as an output, despite having cgi.FieldStorage() enabled.

Essentially, I'm trying to return a calculated value, but I think that my lack of knowledge about indenting has led to my function returning 0.0
The code is posted on pastebin: [Calculator Code](http://pastebin.com/Zfphx9DD)

The problem arises in my getdamage() function (the more than 1000-line long function). The variables in the beginning are empty strings or 0, and if the html form is submitted, and everything is filled in, the variables will have data added to it. I also try to run a calculation within the function in itself (lines 129-131):

```
    if t in moveList:
    basedamageindex += ((int((moveList.index(t)))) +3)
    basedamage+=(int(moveList[basedamageindex]))
```

These three lines were written in order to obtain the "base damage" which is a numerical value in the moveList variable that contains the split .csv file.

```
    damage+= (((2 * (level) + 10)/250)*((attack)/(defense))*((basedamage)+2))
```

This line of code is on line 133 of the pastebin. This is the calculated damage based on all of the data obtained in the form. The following lines: 134-1523 are written to check the "effectiveness" of a move. For example electric is super-effective against water, so damage would be multiplied by 2. These are all if-statements that use previous functions: checkmovetype(x), typea(x), and typeb(x) and check for the types of the pokemon that was filled out in the html form. It then multiplies the line 133 accordingly.
The code finally returns damage with return damage, and the final three lines in the code:

```
print '''<html><body>The damage output should be about ~'''
print getdamage()
print '''</body></html>'''
```

serve to print out the damage.

In conclusion, the calculator will only return 0, but should return a calculated value, when I submit the html form, despite all of the areas being filled in. I feel like this may be a problem with my indenting. Can somebody please check to see if my indenting is incorrect?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Holy redundant parenthesis, batman! You can remove about half of those.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have paranoia about parentheses!

Comment: You can check indentation yourself; run `python -tt` on your script. Pasting your code into a pastebin can easily mask any tab-and-spaces mixing, making such issues almost impossible to debug for us here.

Comment: `basedamageindex += int(moveList.index(t)) + 3` is a lot more readable..

Comment: How is running python -tt on my script accomplished? I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: How do you run your code now?

Comment: I press F5 to run it.

Comment: So you are using IDLE or some other editor to run it? What platform?

Comment: There are no syntax errors highlighted. I'm using IDLE, python 2.7

Comment: What OS? Linux, Windows?

Comment: Open the CMD console (Start menu, type CMD, run it, then use `C:\Python27\python -tt C:\Path\To\Your\Script` to test for indentation problems.

Comment: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"
Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: In Python 2.7, division of two integers is an integer operation, i.e., `3/2` will return 1. Since you seem to operate with integers, might this be causing your problem? Maybe `attack` is less than `defense`, so `attack/defense == 0`?

Comment: When I'm testing it, I'm always using the values 350 for atk and 100 for defense. Still 0 unfortunately